# Can't get the footer to stay at the bottom of the page

Tags: css, positioning

I can't manage the footer of my page to stay at the bottom when I scroll down, I have it on "position: absolute;" and "bottom: 0" but it doesn't work, when I scroll down it goes over the content of the page. I don't want to use position: fixed because I don't want the footer get over my content. Here's my Jsfiddle:  [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zLx65/3/)

Footer:

```
footer {
    position: absolute;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 4px 20px #111;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 4px 20px #111;
    bottom: 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #333;
}
```

Body:

```
body {
    background-image: url(../img/pictures/background3.png);
    background-attachment: fixed;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Do you want it at the bottom of the window, even if that means its not visible on the first view if the page is taller then the browserwindow?

Comment: Exactly, that's just what I want.

Answer (score 2):

This is one method of getting your footer to stay at the bottom of the page, you set a space at the bottom of the body, relative to the height of your footer. This way it won't hover over your content, or be in the centre of the page.

```
body {
    margin: 0 0 50px
}

footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #333;
}
```

Comment: Don't you mean `position: fixed;` ?

Comment: For me this doesn't work :/ maybe I'm doing something wrong, this is my Jsfiddle now http://jsfiddle.net/zLx65/26/ If you meant position: fixed; This is not what I want, I don't want the footer to always occupy its space on the page, I want it to be at the bottom, but if the content has more height than the page, I don't want it to be over the content, sorry for not being enough specific...

Answer (score 1):

Use a "Sticky footer", http://bavotasan.com/2010/creating-a-sticky-footer-for-your-site/. Like the following example (extra `<p>` tags to get a scroll on the window):

### HTML

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="content">
    <p>Here goes the content</p><p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p>Test</p><p>Test</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
  Here comes the footer, always at the bottom of the page
</div>
```

### CSS

```css
html,body{ height:100% }
.wrap{
  height: auto;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.content{
  height: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}
.footer{
  margin-top: -50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `position:fixed` on the footer, should keep it at the bottom.

Comment: I don't wanna use that cause then the footer gets over other elements of the page, I want it to always stay with a margin relative to the content of the page. Thanks anyway.

Comment: It's the only possible solution with CSS. Add padding to the elements that go under the footer equal the footers height (and maybe some more).

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use `position: fixed;` which is a lot like absolute positioning, except it is designed to be sticky to the browser viewport.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `position: relative` and give it a `top margin` of `167px` (your header height which is fixed).

```
footer {
    position: relative;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 4px 20px #111;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 4px 20px #111;
    margin-top: 167px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #333;
}
```